# How to neatly implement interfaces in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am new to Windows development all together and just started using C# and Visual Studio 2015. While writing a class I can implement one interface no problem.

```
public class CMyClass : IFirstInterface
{
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    public void Initialize()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    ...
}
```

Either using the mouse or alt+shift+f10 (I hate these hotkeys. I can't easily hit any with a single hand) I can implement one interface and the stubs appear as expected and in alphabetical order (I assume that is always the case).

However, the moment I try to implement another interface, the code appears in no apparent order. Half of the stubs appear above the `Initialize()` method and half at the bottom of the class. I try to use `#region InterfaceName` and `#endregion` to organize my code, and this auto implement completely ignore it.

It is becoming increasingly difficult to keep my code organized. I am not always certain of every method I need to add, as I'm new to C#, and it is way to easy to pass over stubs that are generated outside of where I expect.

Are there any simple ways to fix this? Can I have VS automatically generated regions as well? I noticed that is was a feature in the previous versions. I hope this question is appropriate for here. I wasn't sure where to post it.

Comment: I don't know if Visual Studio will do it itself (so not writing this as an answer) but I use [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) which gives you a code formatting function that will let you write scripts that will [format your code](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_formatting.html) as you want on a single keypress, it can even automaticly add the #region sections. (P.S. Any key combination can be changed in visual studio, just find it in the keyboard shortcut manager and remap it, think `View.ShowSmartTag` is the thing that is bound to `alt+shift+f10` by default)

Comment: This is possible using Resharper (not free, but highly recommended).